# Error with calculator type program in python ValueError

Tags: python

this is my script, i am new to python but have come to get this, please be forgiving as such in the answers and keep in mind that i am new to this.

```
import functools
numbers=[]

def means():
    end_mean = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, numbers) / len(numbers)
    print(end_mean)

def sum():
    end_sum = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, numbers)
    print(end_sum)

def whatDo():
        print('Input Extra Numbers '+str(len(numbers)+1)+' (or nothing to close):')
        try:
            number= int(input())
            numbers.append(number)
        except:
            print('What do you want to do?')
            answer = input()
            if answer == "mean":
                means()

while True:
    print('Input Number '+str(len(numbers)+1)+' (or nothing to close):')
    try:
        number= int(input())
        numbers.append(number)
    except:
        print('What do you want to do?')
        answer = input()
        if answer == "mean":
            means()
            print('Do you want anything else?')
            reply=input()
            if reply=='no':
                break
            elif reply--'yes':
                whatDo()
        else:
            break
```

However i get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/calculator.py", line 26, in <module>
    number= int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/calculator.py", line 37, in <module>
    elif reply--'yes':
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'
```

after the 'Do you want anything else' and i enter 'yes'.

Comment: The problem is pretty clear:  `reply=='yes'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`elif reply--'yes':` should be `elif reply == 'yes':`

Answer (score 1):

You had a typo

```
elif reply--'yes'
```

it should be, of course

```
elif reply=='yes'
```